# What training do I need for Date Input Views?

Tags: voice, bixby, bixbystudio

What kind of training do I need to get https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/input-view.render.date-picker working with voice input?

I have the following view for selecting a Birthday.

```
input-view {
  match:Birthday

  render{
    date-picker{
      initial-value (now().date)
      restrictions {
        min-allowed ("subtractDuration(now().date, 'P36500D')")
        max-allowed ("subtractDuration(now().date, 'P0D')")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried this training:

```
[g:Birthday:prompt] (January 1st 1950)[v:Birthday]
```

I'd like to be able to say "January 1st 1950" and for this form to interpret that as a date.

Answer (score 0):

For the training, instead of the Birthday model which was a time.Date, I used time.DateTimeExpression and it worked.

```
[g:Birthday:prompt] (January 1st 2019)[v:time.DateTimeExpression]
```